# Django include tag not working

Tags: html, django, templates, include

I am trying to use the Django include tag for the first time and am having some issues. I have written the code below but it gives me an error. I am trying to include a html page which differs for each 'special' (database defined in main.py). The field {{ special.text }} contains a unique website address which should be loaded.

```
{% for special in specials|dictsort:"register_date" reversed %}
<div class="specials_content {{ special.city }}">
{% include {{ special.text }} %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I get is: 
TemplateSyntaxError: 'include' tag takes one argument: the name of the template to be included

Now I think that this is because I have to define it as a variable, but unfortunately I don't understand how to make a variable out of it. Can anybody help?

Comment: You don't "load website addresses" with `include`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So the value of {{ special.text }} would for example be interview-01-vienna.html
The idea is that there is quite a long text with html layout, that is loaded into the website.
So 'website address' should be 'url' probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Second example here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% include special.text %}
```

Comment: Alright templates. I already tried the solution you propose and also used the resource (link) you provided. However if I put it in like that the page doesn't load anymore. (No error, it just gets stuck loading)

Comment: Now it loads somehow, not sure what changed. But it doens't show content and when I 'inspect element' on google chrome, it doesn't show any content either. However, when I take away the INCLUDE tag and just look for {{ special.text }} it shows interview-01-vienna.html as it should.

Comment: @Vincent Are you sure that "interview-01-vienna.html" is full path, not relative. If you are rendering 'interviews/index.html' and want to include 'interviews/interview-01-vienna.html' you should provide full template name ('interviews/interview-01-vienna.html')

Comment: Thanks for your input Igor. The template is just in the 'templates' directory for now, so it should work with the current url I think. No clue what could be causing this cause when I just load the special.text as content it shows the right one. :(